# How to get beans in a hibernate identifier generator?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My application use the Spring and hibernate.

Gotta get the `MyService` bean in the `IdentifierGenerator`.

Example:

```
public class MyGenerator implements org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator, org.hibernate.id.Configurable {

    @Autowired // doesn't work :(
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties properties, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor sessionImplementor, Object obj) {
        ...
```

Comment: You cannot do that as it isn't a spring managed bean. Nor would it probably work as it will generate a circulair dependency. Service needs dao, dao needs hibernate needs generated, needs service ... One workaround is to do a dependency lookup instead of injection, but generally if you want things like this you are doing the wrong thing. Why do you need the service.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really have to do it you can define [`ApplicationContextHolder` utility class](https://gist.github.com/ufuk/5264e0a3c222ed8fc71dca9e6d821959) and use it to store the Spring context:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (ApplicationContextHolder.applicationContext == null) {
            ApplicationContextHolder.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }
    }
  }

  public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
    return applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
  }

  public static <T> T getBean(String qualifier, Class<T> clazz) {
    return applicationContext.getBean(qualifier, clazz);
  }
```

Afterwards use the static method to obtain `MyService` bean:

```
public class MyGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

  @Override
  public void configure(Type type, Properties properties, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
    MyService service = ApplicationContextHolder.getBean(MyService.class);
  }

}
```

This goes against the principle of dependency injection, but sometimes there is not better way if some objects are not managed by Spring.

Comment: I would not like to use `static ApplicationContext`.
I already had problems with this when running in parallel tests with different ApplicationContext.